# Latex Tables with linear and non linear combination of coefficients

Tags: tables, export

I am calculating some coefficients combination in Stata and I am trying to report them on LaTeX.
As you will know, when you perform a linear (or a non linear) coefficients combination on Stata it is necessary to use the `post` command to store the new combined coefficient so that it is possible to export them on LaTeX.
Unfortunately, the `post` command deletes all the previous coefficients besides the last one calculated.

This means that when you export the table in LaTeX you have to put together two tables: one with the original regression and one with only the combined coefficient. As always when exporting two regressions output Stata gives you a two column output (one column for every regression) but I would really like to have everything in one column. Do you know how to do that? Copy and Pasting means changing the LaTeX code which takes ages to do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is this a question about Stata, or about LaTeX?

Comment: I would say both. I can either solve the problem in Latex or in Stata!

Comment: Can you give the output(s) you are able to get from Stata?